# What happens to Snowflake data after it's past the deletion fail-safe point?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I have a Snowflake table containing data and I drop it, what happens to that data? Is it physically purged at any point, or is the storage simply released to the pool of available memory?  If the latter, does the option exist to do an explicit purge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens to Snowflake data after it's past the deletion fail-safe point?

[When the table leaves Fail-safe, it is purged.](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/drop-table.html#usage-notes)

> If I have a Snowflake table containing data and I drop it, what happens to that data?

This is covered in detail in the [Usage Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/drop-table.html#usage-notes) of the DROP TABLE comment.

> Is it physically purged at any point, or is the storage simply released to the pool of available memory?

Based on the above, it's physically purged after it's fail-safe expires.

> If the latter, does the option exist to do an explicit purge?

Can you add some more context as to what you are looking for specifically? Is this GDPR related? Do you need a guarantee it's physically deleted by X days?

Comment: A client is asking about the disposition of their financial transaction data should they choose to go the Snowflake route.  I explained to them that due to the micropartition method SF uses to store the data, even if it's not physically overwritten, it would be nearly impossible to access.  They're new to the cloud scene, we're walking them through the ins and outs.

Comment: I would point them at the docs. Once the fail safe expires it's physically deleted and cannot be accessed.